# How to create a CSR with a UPN SAN using python cryptography module

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I am trying to generate a CSR with a UPN SAN using the python cryptography module

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat._oid import ObjectIdentifier


key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=3072)

with open("rsa.key", "wb") as f:
    f.write(key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    ))

csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder()

csr = csr.add_extension(
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        x509.OtherName(ObjectIdentifier('1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3'), "upn@email.com".encode("utf-8")),
    ]),
    critical=False
)

csr = csr.sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
```

But I get this error :

```
  csr = csr.sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 641, in sign
    return rust_x509.create_x509_csr(self, private_key, algorithm)
ValueError: OtherName value must be valid DER: ParseError { kind: ShortData }
```

How can convert a string to DER binary format ?

Answer (score 0):

ASN.1 strings have types, but assuming UTF8String is acceptable then the valid DER encoding for your example email would be: `\x0c\rupn@email.com`. You can use an ASN.1 DER encoder to do this, but as long as you keep the string length under 128 then the first byte is the ASN.1 tag itself and the second byte is the length (length encoding becomes multi-byte if you exceed 127 bytes). So, assuming your values are < 128 you can take that example and modify the byte value of the length of the string to obtain the value you need (e.g. `upn@email.com` is 13 bytes long so the DER string encodes `\r`, which has ordinal value 13).

Answer (score 0):

I found the python asn1 module to do the DER encoding

```
import asn1

encoder = asn1.Encoder()
encoder.start()
encoder.write('upn@email.com', asn1.Numbers.UTF8String)
print(encoder.output())
```